# Is there any point to doing MessageBox.Show(this, "Message") vs MessageBox.Show("Message")

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there any point to doing `MessageBox.Show(this, "Message")` vs `MessageBox.Show("Message")`?

Won't the dialog default to `this` as owner?

Update: My use case is to call this normally from a method in a win form.

Comment: It's in the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cked7698(v=vs.110).aspx You can use the owner parameter to specify a particular object, which implements the IWin32Window interface, that will serve as the dialog box's top-level window and owner. A message box is a modal dialog box, which means no input (keyboard or mouse click) can occur except to objects on the modal form. The program must hide or close a modal form (typically in response to some user action) before input to another form can occur.

Comment: @Tinwor: He wants to know if there's any difference between the two statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MessageBox.Show(string text)` is implemented like:

```
 public static DialogResult Show(string text) {
            return ShowCore(null, text, String.Empty, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.None, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, 0, false);
    }
```

In `ShowCore` there is a check like:

```
if (owner == null) {
    handle = UnsafeNativeMethods.GetActiveWindow();
}
else {
    handle = Control.GetSafeHandle(owner);
}
```

From: [Reference Source - Microsoft](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/ndp/fx/src/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/MessageBox.cs#315a1c2d2b18bbbd)

So both your call will do the same thing. Since `this` would be the the ActiveWindow.

Comment: "Since `this` would be the active window." Are you certain of that? Seems like a timer, for example, could be running in non-modal form that doesn't have the focus (i.e. isn't the active window). If that timer's tick handler calls `MessageBox.Show`, wouldn't `GetActiveWindow` return the handle to the active window rather than the non-modal form's window?

Comment: @JimMischel, I think the OP is calling both from a same form and that is why I said that `this` or without `this` would point to the same.

Comment: @JimMischel, In my case, that is not an issue, I'm just calling it normally from a method in a win form.

Comment: From my experience you should always call every dialog and every message box passing the correct owner, not relying on the default. If you do not, you'll sooner or later run into more or less subtle issues with window order.